# Detecting dots, minus sign using Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: ocr, tensorflow, convolution, image-recognition, conv-neural-network

I am using Convolutional Neural Network to detect arithmetic operators such as plus (+), minus (-), product (*), dot(.) and parenthesis including MNIST numbers dataset starting from 0 to 9. For the implementation of CNN, I am using Tensor Flow's CNN code with specification of 28x28 training image size. For new training cases of +,-,* and dot(.), I collected a dataset manually in my university and resized it to 28x28.

However, a problem CNN is facing is related to distinguishing between minus and dot in my test cases, where most of my dots are detected as minus signs. Part of the reason is minus (-) sign is wider compared to dot. However, while resized as 28x28, it looses it's inherent property of having a higher aspect ratio. Can someone suggest me a better approach to this problem? or may be an alternative? or a mistake I am doing on my detection?